# Inverting the Hue calculation

Tags: inverse-function

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue), the calculation of a hue from an RGB color input is given as:

$$h_{rgb} = \mathrm{atan}\left( \frac{\sqrt{3} \cdot (G - B)}{ 2 \cdot R - G - B} \right).$$

Where *R*, *G* and *B* are in the range [0, 1], and *h* ranges from [0, 2π]

I'm trying to reverse this calculation. As hues are split in 60 degree portions, some information is known in advance for each of the 6 portions:

- From 0-60 degrees, R = 1, B = 0
- From 60-120 degrees, G = 1, B = 0
- From 120-180 degrees, R = 0, G = 1
- From 180-240 degrees, R = 0, B = 1
- From 240-300 degrees, G = 0, B = 1
- From 300-360 degrees, R = 1, G = 0

For some reason however, when I fill in the known variables in an inverse formula, I end up with a constant value for the unknown variable.  For example, solving for G in the 0-60 degrees portion I get:

G = tan(h) * -2 tan(h) / (-tan(h) * tan(h))

All the tangents eliminate each other and I end up with G = 2. An online Math solver also comes to this conclusion, leading me to believe the formula on Wikipedia is incorrect somehow or I am making a wrong assumption somewhere.

Comment: There are two equations at the place where you took this one.  The first is written in a manner so confused that it is wrong.  You would benefit from using the second version because it correctly indicates the denominator.

Comment: You maybe much happier using the equations at [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) or [other sources](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.html).

Comment: @EricTowers I'm specifically looking for an inverse that does not do an approximation by interpolating between the points of the hexagon that the 6 portions form, I've looked through various papers and tried various solvers so far.  I also found an alternative formula for Hue that does not use arctan, but arccos instead: `h = arccos(((R-G)+(R-B))/(2*sqrt((R-G)^2+(R-B)(G-B))))` but having similar trouble deriving an inverse from that one.